# How to build a web application like TwitterCounter?

Tags: java, web-applications, twitter, diagram

I want to build a application like TwitterCount. Do anyone know any open source application like it? I want to find a open source application which can show some diagram or graph on website. Moreover, I want to build a web application, in which I can copy URL to my application, and it will show some diagrams. Now, my main difficulty about it is how to build a website like this, so I want to get some open source code for reference. If it is implement by java, that is better. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter4J is a Twitter library for Java.](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)

I have a random Twitter bot that I made if you want to see the source.
[Here](https://github.com/crushh87/The-Code-Bot)

Good luck!

Comment: Your link seems unvalid

Comment: Sorry, I realized when I went to it I had some "information" that should not of been there. I can re add the code later if you would like.